# Redirect your output as an html file through terminal

Tags: java

Here is the file which I am trying to get a display in a web browser via terminal on mac.
When I run the program it does not send the program to web browser but it just prints the whole code.
If my understanding is wrong then please let me know.
The following code should give me an output as an html file:

Hello

Hi, how are you?

Code:

```
public class OutputHTML {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // DOCTYPE declaration
    System.out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");

    // html start
    System.out.println("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"en\" xml:lang=\"en\">");

    // head start
    System.out.println("<head>");
    System.out.println();

    // meta tag for encoding
    System.out.println("  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />");
    System.out.println();

    // title
    System.out.println("  <title>" + "Hello" + "</title>");
    System.out.println();

    // head end
    System.out.println("</head>");

    // body start
    System.out.println("<body>");
    System.out.println();

    // heading
    System.out.println("<h1>" + "Hello" + "</h1>");
    System.out.println();

    // simple paragraph
    System.out.println("<p>" + "Hi, how are you?" + "</p>");
    System.out.println();

    // body end
    System.out.println("</body>");

    // html end
    System.out.println("</html>");
}
```

}

Comment: `(java OutputHTML > output.html && open output.html)` from terminal

Comment: Seriously: 1. Open a FileOutputStream, create a printwriter on that stream, use it instead of stdout. 2. use java.awt.Desktop to launch the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the html code to the console, and what you need is to put that code into a file and then launch the browser with that file so the browser itself can render it for you

Answer (score 0):

You're ... printing text to `STDOUT`. It's doing exeactly that.

If you want to create a html file, you'd need to open a file and write to it.

You could create it with your current code using the shell:

```
java OutputHTML > myHtmlFile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your java program to output the HTML code to a file (Java has a number of ways to do this) and write that file to disk in some location you have access to. Then add code to your program to execute a shell command to open the browser and point it at the new HTML file you have created (Again, Java has methods for doing this).